# R: For loop example

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm quite new to R and I am struggling to implement a simple (or maybe not so simple) for loop. Look at the following table:

```
library(data.table) 
data <- 
data.table( stateID    = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2), 
            districtID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1), 
            neighbID   = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1),
            HHID       = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4),
            answer     = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1))
```

I got identifiers for each household (`HHID`), that will find themselves in a certain neighborhood (`neighbID`), which will be in a certain district (`districtID`), which will be in a certain state (`stateID`). Each household will respond to a question and give answers `0`,`1` or `2`.

This is what I want to do: I want to calculate within each neighborhood the proportion of households that responded either `1` or `2` over the total number of households in that neighborhood. I know this can be done using a for loop and I tried to figure it out for my case, but I'm a bit lost.

Any help is highly appreciated <3

Comment: Packages like `dplyr` or `data.table` (which you're already using) make this *much* easier to do without a loop than with a loop. Do you really want to use a loop, or do you want to see a better way to do it?

Comment: @GregorThomas it doesn't have to be a for loop and I am more than open for better ways!

Answer (score 2):

Calling your data `dd`:

```
dd[, .(prop_12 = mean(answer %in% c(1, 2))), by = .(stateID, districtID, neighbID)]
#    stateID districtID neighbID prop_12
# 1:       1          1        1       1
# 2:       1          1        2       0
# 3:       1          2        1       1
# 4:       2          1        1       1
```

Explanation: `answer %in% c(1, 2)` will be TRUE or FALSE based on that condition. When you do math on TRUE/FALSE values they are converted to `1` or `0` automatically. So `sum` of a TRUE/FALSE will give the count of TRUEs, and `mean` of TRUE/FALSE will give the proportion that are TRUE.

And `data.table` lets you do any operation "by group" using the `by` argument. Any intro to `data.table` will cover this well.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the unique values that `neighbID` assumes with `unique`, and then check which rows correspond to that neighborhood with `which`, then use that index to sum only the answers from these rows.

```
for(i in unique(data$neighbID)){
  index = which(data$neighbID==i)
  print(sum(data$answer[index] %in% c(1,2))/length(index))}
```

Answer (score 1):

To round out the answers, here's a dplyr approach. Wordier than data.table but may be more understandable to beginners.

```r
library(dplyr) 
data <- tibble( stateID    = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2), 
                    districtID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1), 
                    neighbID   = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                    HHID       = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4),
                    answer     = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1))
data %>% 
  group_by(stateID, districtID, neighbID) %>%
  summarize(prop_12 = mean(answer %in% c(1, 2))) # like how Gregor Thomas showed.
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#> # Groups:   stateID, districtID [3]
#>   stateID districtID neighbID prop_12
#>     <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1       1          1        1       1
#> 2       1          1        2       0
#> 3       1          2        1       1
#> 4       2          1        1       1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Also equivalent, going step by step:

```
data %>% 
  group_by(stateID, districtID, neighbID) %>%
  summarize(prop_12 = mean(answer %in% c(1, 2)))

data %>%
  group_by(stateID, districtID, neighbID) %>%
  mutate(answer_in_1or2 = answer %in% c(1, 2)) %>%
  summarize(prop_12 = sum(answer_in_1or2)/sum(n()))
```